# Are these two sets same?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A = {∅},
B = {∅,{∅}}

> Please specify the reason.
>   Also what are their cardinalities?

Comment: Answer the second question first, and note that equal sets must have the same cardinality.

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, but the EMPTY could be different, i.e. if U = {1.2.3.4.5} the empty will be everythink else except these elements, however another U let him be U(two) = {9.10.11.12.13} and here the empty will be everythink else except U(two) element`s, moreover u also didnt mention what kind these sets are R or C? I just started learn it, and this is my point be free to correct me

Answer (score 2):

Two sets are the same, iff they have the same elements, that is 
$$ A = B \iff \forall x: (x\in A \leftrightarrow x \in B) $$
To prove $A \ne B$, we will find an element $x \in B$ with $x \not\in A$. Let's look at $x := \{\emptyset\}$. Then $x \in B$ by definition of $B$. To show $x \not\in A$ note that $A = \{\emptyset\}$ has only one element, so $x \not\in A$ iff $x \ne \emptyset$. To see that $x \ne \emptyset$, note that $x$ has one element, namely $\emptyset$, as $\emptyset$ does not have any elements, we have $\emptyset \in x$, but $\emptyset\not\in \emptyset$. Hence $x \ne \emptyset$ and therefore $A \ne B$.

$|A| = 1$ by definition, and $|B| \le 2$. As we already proved above that $\emptyset \ne \{\emptyset\}$, the two listed elements of $B$ are different, hence $|B| = 2$.